# Does tablesorter( plugin-jquery ) work on apex:inputfield?

Tags: jquery, apexinputfield

I am trying to imlement tablesorter but its not working properly on `apex:inputfield`. Here is my sample code..

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" recordSetVar="leads" tabstyle="lead" sidebar="false">
 <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"/>

    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'themes/blue/style.css')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}"/>
 <apex:form >
<style>
.tableSorter1{
 Display:None;
}
</style>
<script>
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'inputs',
    is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        var $c = $(cell);
        // return 1 for true, 2 for false, so true sorts before false
        if (!$c.hasClass('updateInput')) {
            $c
            .addClass('updateInput')
            .bind('keyup', function() {
                $(table).trigger('updateCell', [cell, false]); // false to prevent resort
            });
        }
        return $c.find('input').val();
    },
    type: 'text'
});

$(function() {
    $('table').tablesorter();
});
</script>

 <h2>Dynamic input value sorting</h2>
<p>Add text to the input boxes in the third column, then sort</p>

<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
            <th>Numeric</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <apex:repeat value="{!leads}" var="obj">
        <tr><td><apex:outputField label="testName" value="{!obj.Name}"/></td>

        <td><apex:inputField label="test" value="{!obj.city}"/></td></tr>
         </apex:repeat>

    </tbody>
</table>


  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: <h2>Dynamic input value sorting</h2>
<p>Add text to the input boxes in the third column, then sort</p>

<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
            <th>Numeric</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
        <apex:repeat value="{!leads}" var="obj">
        <tr><td><apex:outputField label="testName" value="{!obj.Name}"/></td>
        
        <td><span><apex:inputField label="test" value="{!obj.city}"/></span></td></tr>
         </apex:repeat>
      
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "not working" are you getting errors, or is it simply not sorting? If it's just not doing anything, refer to my question below.

Comment: Take a look at this example https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html.

Comment: @Keith C -- The main problem is
 'is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },'

this code is returning false for all columns but not for input type, in ideal scenario. But in case of apex:inputfield its returning false. So the rest of the functionality is not working.

Comment: This would work if added a span with "display:none" and the span would hold the same value as the input field

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abondend

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why an `inputField` would cause any huge problems - it just compiles to a standard html `input` with a bit of extra javascript. Your error is probably because you need to use a "no conflict" call to make sure that the standard javascript libraries that Salesforce uses doing conflict with jQuery.

It's pretty easy - just call this first thing in your script tag, or in your onload function:

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then reference `j$` rather than `$` whenever you reference jQuery.

If this doesn't work, in Chrome, right click and choose "inspect element". The Chrome developer console will appear. Any errors will show up at the bottom of the window. If you see any, add them to your question.

Another option is to use an `<apex:input>` object as it is not as sophisticated as an `inputField` and so hence may cause less issues.

Have you tried leaving off the `inputField` to verify that that is indeed causing the issues and that it's not something else - ie the no conflict issue described above?

Comment: I have tried it as well but it is not working too and also at the same time  --var $c = $(cell);-- this statement will create problem if I will use j$.. If there is any other solution please share

Comment: @ CaspNZ --The sorting is not working on apex:inputfield,but  on outputfield it is working fine